# SQL Server - Can someone explain this Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that I can't understand. Can someone explain to me what is going on with all these commas ?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Column1 = TABLE2.Column1, 
TABLE3, TABLE4, TABLE5, TABLE6 
WHERE [...]
```

I don't get the part where a bunch or tables are listed. I figured out by the WHERE part that it was bound or at least used like in a "FROM" use. Can someone explain to me what is it and the name or at least have a link to the documentation of this form of link ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The comma separated list is an older style of inner join (sometimes called implicit join), with the on clause in the where. The preferred syntax is ANSI standard INNER JOIN.

Comment: That is an odd mix of a `LEFT JOIN` and implicit joins. The person who wrote it should really have left 1989 by now though. :) [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you Are Joining `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` using `LEFT JOIN`

So If there is a Matching value in `TABLE2.Column1` for `TABLE1.Column1` that Value will be displayed and if there is no Match, then the Column Will be there but Value will be `NULL`

For all other Tables, you are using a `CROSS JOIN`. So It will create a `Cartesian Product` with the Records obtained from the First Join

```
DECLARE @TABLEA TABLE
(
    ColA INT
)

DECLARE @TABLEB TABLE
(
    ColB INT
)

DECLARE @TABLEC TABLE
(
    ColC INT
)

DECLARE @TABLED TABLE
(
    ColD INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLEA
VALUES(1),(2),(3)

INSERT INTO @TABLEB
VALUES(4),(5),(6)

INSERT INTO @TABLEC
VALUES(7),(8),(9)

INSERT INTO @TABLED
VALUES(10)

SELECT
    *
    FROM @TABLEA A
        LEFT JOIN @TABLEB B
            ON A.ColA = B.ColB
            ,@TABLEC,@TABLED
```

In the above Example, TableA and TableB are LEFT JOINed and then TABLEC AND TABLED are Cross Joined with the Result. So my Final Output will be

```
ColA        ColB        ColC        ColD
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        7           10
1           NULL        8           10
1           NULL        9           10
2           NULL        7           10
2           NULL        8           10
2           NULL        9           10
3           NULL        7           10
3           NULL        8           10
3           NULL        9           10
```

You Can Filter the Records from any of the tables using the `WHERE` Clause